# How to check multiple isset($_POST['something'])?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

How to check multiple `isset($_POST['something'])`? with below mentioned code function is call without set anything? what mistake am I doing

My code is here

```
if(!isset($_POST['username']) || $_POST['email'] || $_POST['password'] || $_POST['confirm_pass'] || $_POST['gender'] || $_POST['country']== "") 

{   $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');    
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $confirm_password = $this->input->post('confirm_pass');
    $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
    $country = $this->input->post('country');
    $this->signupdata->submit_data($username,$email,$password,$confirm_password,$gender,$country);     
 exit(); }
 $this->load->view('signup_view');
```

Comment: `!isset($_POST['username']), $_POST['email']...` or continue adding the same conditional.

Comment: so, OP got their answer and ran off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to check for empty / not set fields may be like this. Play around this to achieve desired results:

```
<?php   
    $req = array("username", "email", "password", "confirm_pass", "gender", "country");
    foreach($req AS $r) {
        if(empty($_POST[$r])) {
            $error = $r . " is a required field";
        } else {
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');    
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $confirm_password = $this->input->post('confirm_pass');
            $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
            $country = $this->input->post('country');
            $this->signupdata->submit_data($username,$email,$password,$confirm_password,$gender,$country);     
            exit();
            $this->load->view('signup_view');
        }    
    }
?>
```

Comment: if you use empty then you dont need `!isset`

Answer (score 3):

`isset` accept multiple variable

In your case, you can do

```
if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['confirm_pass'], $_POST['gender'], $_POST['country']) ) {

}
```

I should also mention that `isset` will only return true if all variable is set

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
>
> From Doc:
>
> If multiple parameters are supplied then isset() will return TRUE only
> if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right
> and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

`empty` returns an error or a notice, if the string is not set.

I personaly use the `!isset` funtions.